# .net - based Help & Support / Knowledge base

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking for a .net-based Help & Support / Knowledge base to plug in to our website. It can be either open source or for purchase. Can anyone make a recommendation as to what are the best products?

Comment: Ok I'm a little OCD on accuracy, but what developer isnt.  Open Source != "free".  It just means you have access to the source code, you may well have to buy the product before they'll send it to you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#Microsoft_ASP.NET) of content management systems like dotnetnuke that can manage this type of information effectively.